# Text data from text file to JSON object

Tags: node.js

I have a text file with below example data.

```
Application.. 4157 10/10/2018 14:24:567 message description 1
Application.. 4157 10/10/2018 14:24:678 message description 2
```

I want this to be transformed to a below JSON file

```
{  [   {
    "appname" : "Application..",
    "PID" : "4157",
    "date" : "10/10/2018",
    "time" : "14:24:567",
    "message":"message description 1"   },
```

{
        "appname" : "Application..",
        "PID" : "4157",
        "date" : "10/10/2018",
        "time" : "14:24:,678",
        "message":"message description 2"   } ] }

Please give me an example how this can be achieved with help of any JSON schema...

I am trying this in node js by reading the text file.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks and Regards,
-Anil Katta

Comment: What *specifically* do you need help with? Do you know how to read the text file? How to process each line? How to split the line into fields? How to create an object? How to add values to an array? How to convert a JavaScript value to JSON?

Comment: I know how to read and process each line, but not sure how to split them into fields and object

Comment: `{ [ ...` is invalid syntax

Comment: @PatrickRoberts just a representation

Comment: Even a simple concrete example should contain valid syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said you can read and process each line, try this code. This code takes the string, removes empty spaces and puts any other words in an array, then you can create the object and pass these array values into object value places, then push the object in your messages array where you will store many messages as objects. When you implement this code with your file, be aware of the loop you are going to use.

Fix credits to [Patrick Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1541563/patrick-roberts).

```
let line = `Application.. 4157 10/10/2018 14:24:567 message description 1`;
const [appname, PID, date, time, ...message] = line.split(' '); 
let messages = [];
messages.push({ appname, PID, date, time, message: message.join(' ') });
```

Example JSON content:

```
[
  {
    "appname":"Application..",
    "PID":"4157",
    "date":"10/10/2018",
    "time":"14:24:567",
    "message":"message description 1"
  },
  {
    "appname":"Application..",
    "PID":"4157",
    "date":"10/10/2018",
    "time":"14:24:567",
    "message":"message description 2"
   }
]
```

Comment: You could just `const [appname, PID, date, time, ...message] = line.split(' '); messages.push({ appname, PID, date, time, message: message.join(' ') });`

Comment: Also your code is wrong because `message` does not contain `message description 1`, just `message`.

Comment: var fs = require('fs'),
    readline = require('readline');

    
    
let messages = [];

var rd = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('C:/DEBUG_1.log'),
    //output: process.stdout,
    console: false
});

rd.on('line', function(line) {
    const [appname, PID, date, time, ...message] = line.split(' ');
    //console.log(line);
    messages.push({ appname, PID, date, time, message: message.join(' ') });
    //console.log(messages)
});

console.log(messages)   ---> still gives an empty array